# Product of diagonals of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

I came across a property which I am not sure if true in general. Suppose you have a parallelogram whose vertices are $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\in\mathbb R^2$. Let's say that the side $[v_1,v_4]$ is parallel to $[v_2,v_3]$. Is it true that

$||v_1-v_4||^2< ||v_1-v_3||\cdot ||v_2-v_4||,$

that is,
the square of one side is less than the product of the diagonals?
I could also be just missing an obvious counterexample, but so far I can't prove it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a rhombus with unit sides which is very long and thin. As it gets
pointier, one diagonal tends to zero and the other to length $2$, so the product
of the diagonals gets very small.